# Delete clicked item in jQuery and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I just have a quick question how do I delete the item I just clicked? I don't have a great way of tracking it and I'm at my last resort way right now (which is what I'm posting) which deletes everything in the list.

PHP/HTML/jQuery:

```
<div class="image-list">
<?php
$count = 1;
if ($hotelId) {
foreach(glob($hotelDir) as $filename=>$hotelvalue){
echo '<li id="del'.$count.'" class="image-list"><a class="enlargeUser" href="'.$hotelvalue.'"><img class="imageListMain" src="'.$hotelvalue.'" width="50px" height="50px"/><p class="filename">' . basename($hotelvalue) . '</p></a> <a class="btn btn-mini btn-primary image-list" style="width: 18px;margin-top: -35px;position: relative\9;top: -25px\9;border-radius: 100%;-moz-border-radius: 100%;-o-border-radius: 100%;-webkit-border-radius: 100%;margin-left:330px;" id="del'.$count.'" value="Delete"><i class="icon-remove-circle icon-2" style="margin-left:-3px;"></i></a></li>' . "\n" . "<br>";
                                $count++;
                            }
                        }else{}
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                    $('div.image-list li a.image-list').live('click', function() { 
                        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this image?", "Cancel", "Confirm", function(result) {
                            if (result) {
                                $('ul.image-list li a.image-list').closest('li').fadeOut(); 
                                $.post('assets/php/deletefile.php');
                            }
                        }); 
                    });
                    </script>
```

Here is the delete information (right now it is static PHP that only deletes the first file I don't have another way of doing this yet):

```
<?php 
session_start();
$files = glob("upload/" . $_SESSION['curHotelId'] . "/" . '*.*');

if(is_file($files[0]))
    @unlink($files[0]);

?>
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to Karl's answer I got a better idea of what I'm doing, but I still cannot get these to remove. I don't know why. They stay blank and act as if they don't even exist or the button does not work.

Here is my updated PHP/HTML/jQuery:

```
<div class="image-list">
                                <?php
                                $count = 1;
                                if ($hotelId) {
                                    foreach(glob($hotelDir) as $filename=>$hotelvalue){
                                        echo '<li data-filename="' . basename($hotelvalue) . '" id="del'.$count.'" class="image-list"><a class="enlargeUser" href="'.$hotelvalue.'"><img class="imageListMain"  data-filename="' . basename($hotelvalue) . '" src="'.$hotelvalue.'" width="50px" height="50px"/><p class="filename">' . basename($hotelvalue) . '</p></a> <a data-filename="' . basename($hotelvalue) . '" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary image-list" style="width: 18px;margin-top: -35px;position: relative\9;top: -25px\9;border-radius: 100%;-moz-border-radius: 100%;-o-border-radius: 100%;-webkit-border-radius: 100%;margin-left:330px;" id="del'.$count.'" value="Delete"><i class="icon-remove-circle icon-2" style="margin-left:-3px;"></i></a></li>' . "\n" . "<br>";
                                        $count++;
                                    }
                                }else{}
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <script>
                            $('li.image-list a.image-list').click( function () {
                                        var filename = $(this).attr('data-filename');
                                        $(this).remove();
                                        $.get('assets/php/deletefile.php?filename=' + filename).done( function() {
                                            // it succeeded
                                        }).fail( function (){
                                            // it failed
                                        });
                                }); 
                            });
                            </script>
```

And the PHP was updated too:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$filename = $_get['filename'];
$files = glob("upload/" . $_SESSION['curHotelId'] . "/" . $filename);

if(is_file($files))
    @unlink($files);

?>
```

HOPEFULLY FINAL UPDATE:

I'm so close, I just wanna throw everything I love out a window. So here is where I'm having an issue. It isn't deleting the images when the code executes so here is PHP:

ALL OF THIS CODE WORKS. C: Thank you everyone that helped!

```
<?php 
session_start();
$file = $_POST['filename'];
$selHotelId = $_SESSION['curHotelId'];
$files = "upload/" . $selHotelId . "/" . $file;
unlink($files);
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#imageClick").live("click", "li.image-list a.image-list", function () {
                                    var _clicked = $(this);
                                    var _filename = _clicked.attr('data-filename');
                                    _clicked.parents("li.image-list").fadeOut(function(){
                                        $(this).empty().remove();
                                    });
                                    $.post('assets/php/deletefile.php', {filename: _filename}).done( function(data) {
                                        bootbox.alert('File has been deleted!');
                                    }).fail( function (error){
                                       bootbox.alert('There has been an error. Contact admin.');
                                    });
                                }); 
                            });
```

Comment: Have you thought about passing the name of the image that was clicked over to the PHP file? Then you could find the matching name in `files` and `unlink` that one.

Comment: See I could POST the name but I have no way of grabbing a specific one so if I do a foreach loop and can create dynamic names but how would I then grab that dynamic name clicked?

Comment: Sure. Unless I'm mistaken, it looks like `$hotelvalue` has the name of the image. You've used this value in plenty of spots, so use a little jQuery to grab the value and pass it in your `$.post`.

Comment: Yea that would possibly worked. I usually avoid doing the URL calls like that but in this case it really shouldn't matter. I have updated my PHP code to handle the GET's so I'll post it.

Comment: See another problem is grabbing the $hotelvalue I'm working on it and messing with a ton of code to handle this but I'm getting no where, the code I just updated with is just more test code with some name changed and attributes added.

Comment: @MikeHuebner You can try the .closest('li') within the other bind. I changed my answer, have a look and let me know.

Comment: @Karl It works with closest('li') but deletes everything within the div, so I'm having a totally different problem now and the $.get doesn't actually delete the file within the directory. I'm getting closer but I think I need a post instead of a get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were still a few issues in your updated code. I've made some changes, and pasted in the code below. I've changed the method to `$.post()`, so your PHP file will need to access the parameter as `$_POST['filename']`.

A couple issues I noticed, you had more than one element with the same `id` attribute. I removed the redundant `data-filename` attributes from elements that didn't need them. I placed your jQuery inside a `$(document).ready()` in order to make sure that nothing was called until all DOM elements had been loaded. I also used the `.on` method for binding the event...just in case you ever dynamically add more `li` elements with the `a.image-list` element. This way you are binding the event to an element that will always be there, and catching it on the `a.image-list`. (I might be explaining that incorrectly...it's late).

Hope this helps.

```
<ul class="image-list">
<?php
    $count = 1;
    if ($hotelId) {
        foreach(glob($hotelDir) as $filename=>$hotelvalue){
            echo '<li id="del'.$count.'" class="image-list"><a class="enlargeUser" href="'.$hotelvalue.'"><img class="imageListMain" src="'.$hotelvalue.'" width="50px" height="50px"/><p class="filename">' . basename($hotelvalue) . '</p></a> <a class="btn btn-mini btn-primary image-list" style="width: 18px;margin-top: -35px;position: relative\9;top: -25px\9;border-radius: 100%;-moz-border-radius: 100%;-o-border-radius: 100%;-webkit-border-radius: 100%;margin-left:330px;" title="Delete" data-filename="' . basename($hotelvalue) . '" ><i class="icon-remove-circle icon-2" style="margin-left:-3px;"></i></a></li>' . "\n" . "<br>";
            $count++;
         }
    }
?>
</ul>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul.image-list").on("click", "li.image-list a.image-list", function () {
            var _clicked = $(this);
            var _filename = _clicked.attr('data-filename');
            _clicked.parents("li.image-list").fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).empty().remove();
            });
            $.post('assets/php/deletefile.php', {filename: _filename}).done( function(data) {
                // it succeeded
            }).fail( function (error){
                // it failed
            });
        }); 
    })  
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** I had a typo in my code...not sure you caught it.

`var _filename = clicked.attr('data-filename');`

**SHOULD BE...**

`var _filename = _clicked.attr('data-filename');`

My apologies.

To see if you are hitting your PHP file, you can do something simple like this...

```
<?php
    $data["response"] = $_POST['filename'];
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

And then modify your `.done` method to look like this...

```
$.post('assets/php/deletefile.php', {filename: _filename}).done( function(data) {
     // it succeeded
     console.log(data);
}).fail( function (error){
     // it failed
});
```

Comment: I did alerts running through the whole code in 4 different sections and it only gets to the first one which I posted right under the event fire. So, for some reason that is not working either and it isn't going through all the way.

Comment: Update! So it does execute fully but it won't go to the file at all. So I'll try seeing what it is doing.

Comment: When you say, "it won't go to the file"...I assume you mean it's not hitting the PHP code found at `assets/php/deletefile.php`? In your debug tools (I'd look at the Network tab), are you receiving a 500 error...a 404? Did you make the change from $_GET['filename'] to $_POST['filename']?

Comment: Yes I did I changed everything over and I am posting and it is deleting from the list but not the directory itself. So that is what I've been working on, and now I'm converting uploads to FTP, its been a busy day haha. But I still cannot grab the name of the file to delete. I updated your code below with more of my code and I caught your typos and chanced quite a bit around. Your file: _filename doesn't pick up extremely well but it does seem to work. I'll get back to you in a few minutes after testing. Thank you so much for you help you have no idea.

Comment: It is definitely running the delete command no problem. Everything deletes as is and goes but doesn't delete in the directory itself so I'm debugging the PHP (well trying to) and it doesn't seem to want to delete. I'll post my PHP code.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure your original PHP code wasn't working because `is_file()` would return false when passed the `array` that's returned from `glob()`. If the code worked, feel free to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yea, it worked, now I get to work on uploading multiple files as once. Haha.

Comment: You should check out FilePicker...I think they changed the name to Ink or something. Here's the URL: https://www.inkfilepicker.com/ . Does the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete or remove a DOM element with jQuery using a syntax similar to this and pull the value passed in your item:

```
$('div.image-list li a.image-list').click( function () {
    var filename = $(this).attr('data-filename');
    $(this).parents('li').remove();
});
```

You will have pass the data to the PHP file like you are doing but with the filename in the url:

```
$.get('assets/php/deletefile.php?filename=' + filename).done( function() {
    // it succeeded
}).fail( function (){
    // it failed
});
```

When you load the page you will have to load in the `data-filename="filename.jpg"` into the element you clicked.

In your deletefile.php, you can use `$_GET['filename']` to get the filename.

Comment: Nice edits. If you are `POST`ing, you'd want to access the parameter with `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, though. Although, then you'd want to pass the data correctly as well (passed in as an argument to the `$.post` method). Your solution would work as written. Sorry.

Comment: Good point, thanks @fletch I missed that. I changed it to a .get().

Comment: Nice job on your answer!

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, it is weird they don't remove on click.

Comment: @MikeHuebner You can try the `.closest('li')` within the other bind. I changed my answer, have a look and let me know.

Comment: I've used closest before, it grabs it but it is iffy sometimes and in some browsers it won't work unless I clear the cache onload everytime. So if this is the only way to do it I might just right up a script that does something similar, thanks again Karl! I'm testing it now... Yea it does not seem to want to work. I tried getting rid of the (this) and that doesn't work either. I'm trying a bunch of different methods, if you have any more ideas let me know and I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having no luck, it is as if the button (the button echo'd in the php) doesn't even have an event tied to it. So I'm a bit lost. Sorry for the multiple comments just updating with what I got.

Comment: @MikeHuebner I changed the .closest to .parents(li) to select the li parent of the clicked item. To test if the event is firing on click, put `alert('monkey!');` under your `.click( function() {`, that way you will know if it is properly bound to the event.

Comment: I am doing that now, and the event fires and then quits it is a weird thing happening lol.

Comment: @MikeHuebner try placing that alert under the `.get(` where I placed the comment `// succeed`. If it alerts you, that means the post is working. I also noticed you put `data-filename=""` in your `li`. You should put that in the `<a>` that you are clicking. Let me know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34115/discussion-between-karl-and-mike-huebner)

Comment: I cleared a bunch of code and restarted and used @fletch 's code and the jQuery cancels itself out after the event fires so I'm debugging right now. Keep in mind I'm using an older version of jQuery (for the sake of DataTables) which is 1.8.2